# Proving Rules of Differentials

Tags: differential

Show that for any two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ we have $d(f+g)=df+dg$.

Not too sure how to go about this. How would I set up the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Use this fact: $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

Comment: So would it become: d(f+g)=((∂f/∂x)dx+(∂f/∂y)dy)+((∂g/∂x)dx+(∂g/∂y)dy)

Comment: Yes you are right. And you should proceed according as Bye_World has said.

Comment: @j.stat You'll want to start with $d(f+g) = \frac{\partial(f+g)}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial(f+g)}{\partial y}dy$ and after some steps get $=df+dg$.

Comment: So is (∂(f+g)/∂x)dx=(∂f/∂x)dx+(∂g/∂x)dx? Or do I have to do some algebra to prove this?

Comment: No separate algebra. Your statement is correct and enough.

Answer (score 0):

The differential operator $d/dx$ is defined as:

$$\dfrac{d f(x)}{dx}=\lim_\limits{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

So $d(f+g)$ becomes:

$$\dfrac{d [f(x)+g(x)]}{dx}=\lim_\limits{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)+g(x+h)-f(x)-g(x)}{h}$$

$$=\lim_\limits{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\lim_\limits{h\to0} \dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$

$$=\dfrac{d f(x)}{dx}+\dfrac{d g(x)}{dx}$$

$$=d(f)+d(g)$$